# How to share Firebase data with two different apps

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I've successfully inserted data into my firebase database.(Client App).
Now all I have to do is to retrieve data back into a text view but in a different application.(Admin Application).

```
public void clients()
    {
        String name="Abch";
        String gender="Abcg";
        String barber="Abcf";
        String concern="Abce";
        String dt="Abcd";

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(gender) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(barber) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(concern) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(dt))
        {
            String id=databaseReference.push().getKey();
            client client=new client(id,name,gender,barber,concern,dt);

            databaseReference.child(id).setValue(client);
            Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong Please Check Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added a login page for the admin,after admin login -  then on a button click the admin must get to see all the firebase database contents.

Comment: You should show what you've done so far, to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Just connect the admin app to the same firebase project and fetch the data using any valueEventListener

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Added code.

Comment: @JinsonPaul Can you explain more.

Comment: databaseReference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @ Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot post:dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){

                    Client client =post.getValue (Client.class);
                    /// code to display the valuess

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );

Comment: Hey @AkashNair do mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark or V type looking button next to the answer, as this helps people on stack overflow with similar questions, and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the data in another application, you have to use `eventListeners`, provided you have set the rules of your database right.

There are three `eventListeners` you can use namely, `singleValueEventListener`, `valueEventListener` and `childEventListener`. Since you have not posted the structure of your database, I'm assuming you know how to get the required `DatabaseReference`.

```java
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                   Client client = ds.getValue(Client.class);   

                }

            }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: @AkashNair reading/writing access to users. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBjMnz_dreAhVSblAKHYmcBWsQjBAwBHoECAUQCw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdatabase%2F&usg=AOvVaw2kmBWUCRePwiHLl_uw9ZIU. Do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V type tick button next to the answer, it should turn green, this helps stack overflow readers, and I'd also appreciate that. Cheers! :)